# TiKz dash dash plus plus

Tags: tikz-pgf

Unfortunately due to the way search engines work, this information isn't that easy to find.

Sometimes examples draw using `--`, sometimes `-- +`, sometimes `-- ++`.

I don't get the meaning!

For example, for this command:

```
\draw[fill=gray!50] (1,1) -- + (0:.5) arc (0:60:1) -- cycle;
```

What is the `-- +` there?

What does it mean if I change that to `--` ?

Comment: I've added a reference to the manual for further reading.

Comment: Which is [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf/)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The pluses modify the following coordinate making it relative to the previous saved coordinate.  The difference between a single and a double plus is whether or not the saved coordinate is updated.

Thus:

```
\draw (1,1) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1);
```

the second coordinate is actually `(1,1) + (1,0) = (2,1)` and the third is `(2,1) + (0,1) = (2,2)`.

```
\draw (1,1) -- +(1,0) -- ++(0,1);
```

the second coordinate is actually `(1,1) + (1,0) = (2,1)` but the second coordinate is not saved so the third is relative to the *first* and thus is `(1,1) + (0,1) = (1,2)`.

There's a slight change for bezier curves.  If you do `\draw (1,1) .. controls +(1,0) and +(0,1) .. ++(2,2)` then the second control point is computed relative to the **end** point (which is very useful) and thus the controls are `(1,1) + (1,0)` for the first and `(2,2) + (1,1) + (0,1)` for the second (as the end point is itself relative to the initial position since the control points were specified with a single plus).

(Forgot to add the reference to the manual: to learn more, see Section 13.4 in the PGF manual (PGF2.10 version, might be a different section in other versions))