# how can I draw the radius of an arc using r * (cos (angle) and sin (angle))

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, arc

i want to draw an arc of circle, and figure out the raduis on the graph, using:

> raduis\times cos and sin 45\deg

**when i specify the radius r=1.5cm, i can't get it on the border, anyone can help me, thanks in advance**

```
\documentclass[border=30pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, decorations.markings, quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, violet] (0,0) -- (4,0);
      \node[left] at (0,0){$O$};
     \node[right] at (4,0){$O'$};
    \fill[red] (2,0) circle (1.1pt);
    \draw[thick, red] (2,0) -- ({1.5*cos(40)},{1.5*sin(40)});
     \draw (3.5,0) arc (0:180:1.5) ;\node[above] at (2.5,0){$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `++`.

```
\documentclass[border=30pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, decorations.markings, quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, violet] (0,0) -- (4,0);
      \node[left] at (0,0){$O$};
     \node[right] at (4,0){$O'$};
    \fill[red] (2,0) circle (1.1pt);
    \draw[thick, red] (2,0) -- ++({1.5*cos(40)},{1.5*sin(40)});
     \draw (3.5,0) arc (0:180:1.5) ;\node[above] at (2.5,0){$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answers which are very fast and very useful

Comment: In place of `({1.5*cos(40)},{1.5*sin(40)})` you should probably use `(40:1.5)`, and you can add only one `+` here ;)

Comment: @Kpym I agree with all these statements, but the reason why the original code didn't work was that at least one `+` was missing.

Answer (score 1):

For calculations, you can use the \tikzmath command in tikz. This requires you to load the appropriate library:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
```

You then define define variables inside the \tikzmath command and use these variables as coordinates, e.g.:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{
        \angle = 40;
        \coordX = 1.5 * cos(\angle);
        \coordY = 1.5 * sin(\angle);
    }
    \draw[thick, red] (2,0) -- ++(\coordX,\coordY);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm not quite sure if this will work since I've only used \tikzmath once so far. Hope this helps and doesn't contain too many mistakes (**code is untested, math library apparently not necessary...see comment below**).

Comment: looks like someone beat me to it =)

Comment: You should add `+` or `++` to obtain the radius of the arc as asked in the question. And you don't need `math` library for this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Kpym. Had to google what ++ does ([answer is here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66094/tikz-dash-dash-plus-plus)), learnt something new, and edited my post. Thank you =).