# Help on LateX Diagram using TikZ package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new to Latex and I would like to know if you could help me with this diagram. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: there on site are many answer for similar drawings. search it, select one which is most similar to you and use it as starting point. if you will stuck in your accommodate of it to your desired image, ask for help. so far this is question: do-this-for-me which likely be closed as "to broad".

Comment: @Zarko I am new to Latex and Stackexchange. I will do my research. If I cannot do it, I will come back. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick proposal with some comments. Now, it's time to read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779/156344).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\sffamily
% The main nodes
\node[minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=2cm,text centered,draw] (a) {Traning};
\node[minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=2cm,text centered,draw,right=2cm of a] (b) {Prediction};
% The arrow in the middle
\draw[->] (a)--(b) node[midway,above,align=center,font=\footnotesize] (mid) {Model\\Parameter};
% The ellipse node at the bottom needs `shapes' library
\node[below=1.5cm of mid,ellipse,draw] (mod) {Model};
\draw[->] (mod) -| (a); % Read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481195/156344
\draw[->] (mod) -| (b); %
% The outside arrows: take care of the direction of the arrow
% Read more in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66094/156344
\draw[<-] (a.west) -- ++ (-1,0) node[left,align=center,font=\footnotesize] {Ground\\Truth};
\draw[->] (b.east) -- ++ (1,0) node[right,font=\footnotesize] {Prediction};
\draw[<-] (a.north) -- ++ (0,1) node[above] {Observation};
\draw[<-] (b.north) -- ++ (0,1) node[above] {Observation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]