# Omit the same coordinate parameters in drawing line in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

When I draw lines using Ti*k*Z, I always need to specify coordinates. For example

```
\draw (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1);
```

It is getting tedious when you have a lots of draws.

My question: "Is there a way to simplify the coordinate parameters?"

For example, if the coordinate parameter (on *x* or *y* axis) are the same, we can just omit it. More specifically,

```
\draw (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1);
```

can be written as

```
\draw (1,0) -- (0,-) -- (-,1);
```

(I use `-` to show the parameter in this position  is the same as the one before)

Comment: I would use `-|` and `|-` for that purpose, instead of `--`. For example, in this case, I would use `\draw (1,0) -| (0,1);`.

Comment: What about more than 3 coordinates

Comment: Give me an example, and I will do it for you. A combination of `--`, `-|`, and `|-` will solve it all.

Comment: Yes, it is true you can use combinations of these to draw almost any line. In this case, my question seems trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with you that you should not have a command in which the *x* coordinate (or *y* coordinate) is useless in the relative positioning of the points.

However, it is not that easy to have such a command you requested. Nevertheless, Ti*k*Z already gives you a more brillant solution: [`-|` and `|-`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481195/156344), which can handle named coordinates like `(a)`, `(b)`, etc. (and you will know that named coordinates are much prefered when drawing figures).

Some example:

```
\draw (x1,y1) -- (x1,y2) -- (x2,y2);
```

can be changed to

```
\draw (x1,y1) -| (x2,y2);
```

Or with five coordinates:

```
\draw (x1,y1) -- (x1,y2) -- (x2,y2) -- (x2,y3) -- (x3,y3) -- (x3,y4);
```

can be changed to

```
\draw (x1,y1) |- (x2,y2) -| (x3,y3) -- (x3,y4);
```

As I said, a combination of `--`, `-|` and `|-` can do anything related to this. At worst there can be a couple of replicated *x* (or *y*) coordinates, but that is not a great deal,  especially when you mostly have to deal with named coordinates in the future.

Furthermore, you can specify relative coordinates by prepending [`+` or `++`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66094/156344) to the coordinates. Your example would be translated to

```
\draw (x1,y1) -- ++(0, dy1) -- ++(dx1, 0);
```

A single `+` leaves the reference point in place, while a `++` moves the reference point to the current location. This makes it very easy to move parts of a sketch around. You only have to edit the first coordinate.